# python regex grouping

Tags: python, regex

Given string `s = '(A /something_1)(B /something_2)(C /something_3),/,(D /something_4)(D /something_5)'`

I would like to get this output: `(C /something_3),/,(D /something_4)(D /something_5)`

I keep matching the whole string s, instead of getting above substring.

I am using `re.search(r'(\(C.*\)),/,(\(D.*\))+')`

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just about there - `re.search(r'(\(C.*\)),/,(\(D.*\))+', s).group()` will get you what you want.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '(A /something_1)(B /something_2)(C /something_3),/,(D /something_4)(D /something_5)'
>>> re.search(r'(\(C.*\)),/,(\(D.*\))+', s).group()
'(C /something_3),/,(D /something_4)(D /something_5)'
```

Are you wanting to further split that in groups?

Answer (score 1):

Using Python 2.7, I get the exact result you're after:

```
import re
s = '(A /something_1)(B /something_2)(C /something_3),/,(D /something_4)(D /something_5)'
m = re.search(r'(\(C.*\)),/,(\(D.*\))+', s)

s[m.start():m.end()] == '(C /something_3),/,(D /something_4)(D /something_5)'
```